# "git branch --contains" -- difference between "* (no branch)" and no output

Tags: git

I'm using git 1.7.1 accessing checkout of a bitbucket.org repository.

I have two tags: `TAG1` and `TAG2`. I run:

```
git branch --contains `git rev-list -1 TAG1`

git branch --contains `git rev-list -1 TAG1`
git branch --contains `git rev-list -1 TAG2`
```

Note that in each case `git rev-list` returns a valid hash. There's no problem with that part of the command. I may as well be asking about 
two distinct commits.

The first command has the output:

```
  * (no branch)
```

The second command has no output at all. My first question is, what
is the difference between the output `* (no branch)` and no output?

My second question is, how would one create a tag that gives no output in response to the above commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a brief note: there is no need to do `git rev-list -1 <name>`.  You can usually just use `<name>` directly, and if not, `git rev-parse <name>` gets you the hash ID without doing a commit-graph walk (i.e., `git rev-list -1 <name>` or `git rev-list --no-walk <name>` produces the *same* hash ID as `git rev-parse <name>`).

#### Question 1: `git branch --contains`: no output vs "no branch"

No output at all means no branches were found that matched your criteria.  To explain `* (no branch)`, though, look to the output from `git branch`, and consider the "detached HEAD" case:

```
$ git branch
  diff-merge-base
* master
  precious
  stash-exp
```

The starred branch is my current branch.  If I now check out a specific commit by hash ID or similar "specific-commit-finder", so as to get into "detached HEAD" mode, and run `git branch` again:

```
$ git checkout master~5
Note: checking out 'master~5'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at 1f73ff0... Merge branch 'jk/reset-to-break-a-commit-doc-updated'
$ git branch
* (HEAD detached at 1f73ff0)
  diff-merge-base
  master
  precious
  stash-exp
```

You can see I am now on a branch that has no name: it's the branch whose tip commit is `1f73ff0`.  If I look for branches that *contain* commit `1f73ff0` or one of its ancestors, I should find my current, unnamed branch ... and I do:

```
$ git branch --contains HEAD
* (HEAD detached at 1f73ff0)
  master
```

The reason my Git says `(Head detached at ...)` is that mine is newer than yours; older versions just said `(no branch)`.  In any case, this can *only* occur when you are in detached HEAD mode, and the no-name branch that you are on is the one to which `HEAD` points.  As you move your `HEAD` around throughout the various commits in the Git history, this no-name branch will change from commit to commit.

You may, as Git noted above, create a *new* branch name at any time, pointing to any existing commit.  To point to the current (`HEAD`) commit—whether or not your HEAD is detached—you can use `git checkout -b <new-branch-name>`.  To point to (and simultaneously check out) some *other* commit by its hash ID, or by relative names like `master~30`, you would use `git checkout -b <new-branch-name> <hash-ID-or-relative-name>`.  You can also create new branch names without checking anything out, nor moving your HEAD in any way, using the `git branch` command: `git branch thirtyback master~30`, for instance—and you can *delete* a branch name at any time as well, e.g., `git branch -D thirtyback` (`-D` is "force delete", i.e., delete whether or not it's "safe"; use `-d` to get some safety-belt checking applied).

(To re-attach my HEAD to `master` I now run `git checkout master`.)

#### Question 2: how can a commit be on no branches at all?

Easily, really. :-)  A commit is "on" any branch where, by starting from the commit to which that branch points, Git can *find* that commit, through the usual commit-graph walk.

Consider this drawing:

```
... <- E <- F <- G   <-- branch
```

where each single letter represents a commit hash.  The name `branch` *points to* (contains the ID of) commit `G`.  Commit `G` points to (contains the ID of) commit `F`, and `F` points to `E`, and so on.

This means that, if you select-with-history (as `git rev-list` does), the name `branch` refers to every commit starting with `G` and working backwards.

Now let's add another branch to the drawing (and since there are no text arrows that point up or down *and* leftward, I will stop drawing internal arrows):

```
       F--G   <-- branch
      /
...--E
      \
       H--I   <-- anotherbranch
```

Now commits `F` and `G` are on `branch` as before, and `H` and `I` are on `anotherbranch`.  But commit `E` is on *both* branches.

Now let's take a look at the same graph, but where the branch name `anotherbranch` has been removed:

```
       F--G   <-- branch
      /
...--E
      \
       H--I   [abandoned]
```

Commits `H` and `I` remain in the repository until garbage collected, so we can use `git branch --contains` on their hash IDs.  Before they go away—perhaps even before we delete the *branch* name—let's add a *tag* name pointing to commit `H`:

```
       F--G   <-- branch
      /
...--E
      \
       H--I   [abandoned]
       ^
       |
    tag:foo
```

The tag name `foo` now guarantees that commit `H` remains in the repository forever (or until tag `foo` is deleted).  Commit `I` still has no name at all, and still gets garbage-collected eventually, giving:

```
       F--G   <-- branch
      /
...--E
      \
       H
       ^
       |
    tag:foo
```

If we ask which branches contain commit `H`, the answer is none—unless, of course, we `git checkout foo`, which gives us a detached HEAD with `HEAD` naming commit `H`, in which case the answer is `* (no branch)` or `* (HEAD detached at ...)`.